# TChromeTabs - How to set tab icon from http ( or file )?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I know how set icon tabs via TChromeTab.ImageIndex.

```
chTabs: TChromeTabs;

chTabs.Tabs[i].ImageIndex := 0;
chTabs.Tabs[i].SpinnerState := tssNone;
```

How to assign ico directly from http or file?

Comment: Add the Icon to the ImageList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image list and image index are the way to specify the icon. Therefore you need to download the icon, add it to the image list, and set the image index to be that of the newly added icon.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone, I thought that there is an easier way - something like FORM.Icon.LoadFromFile (xx)